# Laravel 5: Uploaded image can't be displayed and file permission

Tags: laravel, permissions, upload, unlink

In my Laravel 5 project, I uploaded image to my sub folders of the public folder. Example: public/uploads/logos/imagename.jpg. The image is uploaded successfully but I have two problems:

1. I can't display the image in the view using `<img src="uploads/logos/imagename.jpg">`. The error says that file is not found.
2. When using below code to delete the image, I got another problem of file permission:

   $path ="uploads/logos/imagename.jpg"; 
   if(file_exists($path)) { unlink($path); }

Please kindly advise how to upload properly, delete uploaded file, and display the uploaded image.

Thanks, Naren

Comment: Try `<img src="{{ asset('uploads/logos/imagename.jpg') }}">`.

Comment: And #2 doesn't work, because your file isn't in `uploads`. It's in `public/uploads`. Consider using the proper Laravel function `File::delete('path')` for it, too.

Answer (score 0):

There are several laravel and third party features that can solve this issue for you, for a better exponation, let's solve a common problem, uploading an user avatar:

you have the following form:

```
<form method="POST" action="/avatar" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrf_field() }}
        <div>
           <input name="avatar" type="file">
        </div>
<div class="margin-top-10">
    <input type="submit" class="btn green" value="Submit" /> 
</div>
```

that is the form to upload a file, note that you need to put `accept-charset` and `enctype` attributes in order to the file field works with your backend. After this, you have to make your controller to upload the avatar, imagine you have the `ProfileController` class, simply as this action:

```
public function set_profile_picture(Request $request) {
        $user = $request->user();
        if (!$request->hasFile('avatar')) {
            Flash::error('Avatar not found');
            return redirect('/profile');
        }
        $path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');
        $user->avatar = $path;
    $user->save();
    return redirect('/profile');
}
```

Check that you can get the file from the frontend form by using `$request->file(avatar)`, with that done, you need to define the route: `Route::post('/avatar', 'Auth\\ProfileController@set_profile_picture');`

And finally, you need to make another thing to show the picture uploaded, you have to choices, storing the file in the server is made by the `Storage` Facade in Laravel, so, you will find out that you cannot give public access to these files because they are in a folder named `storage`, you can always make a symbolic link to the folder containing the avatars to have access to them in the `public` folder where you have the front controller and all those stuffs, but if you are using some VCS like git, this symlink could bring you problems in the future, the most secure way to do this is to define another action in your controllers to access a private file in your storage, the following is the better way to do this:

```
 Route::get('avatars/{filename}', function ($filename) {

   $path = storage_path() . '/app/avatars/' . $filename;
   if(!File::exists($path)) abort(404);

   $file = File::get($path);
   $type = File::mimeType($path);

   $response = Response::make($file, 200);
   $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

   return $response;
});
```

You can find more information about the Storage Facade in the laravel official documentation, to unlink a file is simple `\Storage::Delete('/path/to/file.jpg');`

Hope it helps you this little exponation, bests! ;)

Comment: Sorry for late reply, and thanks for your advice. I just realize that the problem is because I removed "public" from url so I did move files to sub folder "jobs". Then I changed require __DIR__.'/jobs/bootstrap/autoload.php'; and $app = require_once __DIR__.'/jobs/bootstrap/app.php'; in my index.php file (in root directory). Everything works well, except how to display those uploaded images.

Please kindly advise on this